# How to call assert for several time until it's true?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

Say that I got some basic assert as below:

`expect(myObject.getValue()).to.equal(5);`

And the returned value from `myObject.getValue()` should be `5` after several code running over some other place, so I just need to let this `value` to be updated.

My question is, what is the code for creating this kind of test?

Comment: Why not run the code several times and then do the assert?

Comment: I agree with @VsevolodGoloviznin, however, would also like to ask what is it that determines the state internally? If it's something that can be abstracted then it'd be simpler to just mock/stub what state `myObject` needs to be in prior to calling `getValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha has a facility for [retrying tests](https://mochajs.org/#retry-tests). You can just use `this.retries(number_of_tries)` in your test. Like this:

```
it("something", function () {
    this.retries(10);
    expect(myObject.getValue()).to.equal(5);
});
```

You can also use it in a `describe` block if you want to set the number of retries for an entire set of tests. Note that if you use `this.retries`, it cannot appear in an arrow function (`() => ...`) because arrow functions let `this` remain the value it had in the scope in which the arrow function appeared. You must use a full function (`function () ...`).

Answer (score 0):

For greater precision over what is being retried use the [retry-assert](https://github.com/ncjones/retry-assert) library:

```
const activeUser = await retry()
    .fn(() => getUser(id))
    .until(user => expect(user).toHaveProperty('active', true))
```

Retrying the entire test is too coarse grained when writing higher level functional tests - for example when testing APIs that have asynchronous state changes - and is not an option with CucumberJS. Retry Assert works with any test runner and will give meaningful error messages when your retried assertion fails too many times.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of retry-assert.