# How to retry chaijs expect assertions multiple times before declaring the test as "failed"

Tags: javascript, chai, assertion, cucumberjs

I am not using Mocha as my test runner, I am using cucumberJs. Is there a way to re-run just the expect condition for a given number of times before declaring the step to be failed?

suppose a simple (but non-realistic) step be:

```js
Given(/^I want to check the username to be John$/, (name: string)=>{
   expect(name).to.be.equals('John'); 
});
```

Now, if the name is Sam, the expect condition will fail. But, i want run the expect condition at least 5 times before declaring it to be failed. Is there any chaijs configuration/plugin available to achieve the same?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, Chai does not have any such feature. It looks like [MochaJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386037/how-to-call-assert-for-several-time-until-its-true) does have something to achieve this. if you still want to use chai, this is something that works.

```
Given(/^I want to check the username to be John$/, (name: string) => {
  let retry = 3;
  for (let index = 0; index < retry; index++) {
    try {
      expect(name).to.be.equals('John');
      index = retry + 1;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(index);
      if (index == retry - 1) throw new Error('Failed')
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This still not serves the purpose. I am looking for more native solution in chai config level, do that expect itself can retry the same

Comment: Unfortunately, chai does not have any such configuration as far as  I know. Maybe you should look at some other testing libraries.

Comment: I have added another link which might be of some help to you.

Comment: I knew, thats why started my question with 'I am not using Mocha...' . Thanks for the help though.